# PHP remote file upload progress bar

Tags: php, linux, file-upload

I want to upload file from frontend to remote server via PHP and progress bar, how could I do this?
May be it is possible without installing extra software on frontend and remote servers?

On frontent server a have apache, PHP
On remote server a have nginx, PHP-FPM

Comment: Tons of resources out there on this already, please try looking beforehand. e.g. https://youtu.be/pP8MexNb7QM https://stackoverflow.com/q/15410265/2773837 https://stackoverflow.com/q/3586919/2773837 https://stackoverflow.com/q/2704314/2773837 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48819619/2773837 http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Dude, most of your links are not about uploading file with progress bar to remote server...

Comment: What specific issues are you having? Do you have a complete, minimal, and verifiable example? What have you tried that does not work? I posted links since it appears you need a starting point.

Comment: I did't know how to start solving this but now i tried example from your link youtu.be/pP8MexNb7QM and it looks good for me, i need to add percents to progressbar but anyway the main task is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[you can view this question in details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery). anyways when you call ajax request from query where is a function called `uploadProgress` you can call and track the status and percentage on file uploading in server. this function accept four parameters `event, position, total, percentComplete`

example

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
         // reset your progress bar here or do anything before making a call to endpoint
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        $('#progressBar').width(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```